# Gnuplot Function

Tags: function, input, gnuplot

How can I plot a function with x being a value from my datafile? Something like that:

```
set encoding utf8
set term postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvetica, 20"
set output 'kernel.eps'

# Mean  & Standard Deviation
load "mean_sd.dat"

# Bandwidth
h = 1.6*sd*n**(-0.2)

# Kernel Function
K(x) = exp(-x*x/2.0)/(sqrt(2.0*pi))

# PLOT --> THIS DOES NOT WORK
# EACH VALUE IN $2 MUST BE USED FOR A SINGLE K(X)
plot for [i=1:n] 'probability.dat' using 0:(K((x - $2)/h))
```

My data file 'probability.dat':

```
366.000000   3.153012 
366.000000   4.211409 
366.000000   3.845248 
366.000000   4.131654 
366.000000   3.956508
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your question correctly, but if you want to plot the kernel function for all values from the second column, then one could proceed for example as follows:

```
set encoding utf8
set term postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvetica, 20"
set output 'kernel.eps'

# Mean  & Standard Deviation
sd=1
n=1

# Bandwidth
h = 1.6*sd*n**(-0.2)

# Kernel Function
K(x) = exp(-x*x/2.0)/(sqrt(2.0*pi))

# PLOT --> THIS DOES NOT WORK
# EACH VALUE IN $2 MUST BE USED FOR A SINGLE K(X)

fname = 'probability.txt'
N = system(sprintf("wc -l %s | gawk '{print $1}'", fname))

cmd(i) = system(sprintf("gawk 'NR==%d{print $2;exit}' %s", i, fname))

set key left top reverse

set xr [-10:10]
plot for [i=1:N] K((x - cmd(i))/h) title sprintf("%.3f", real(cmd(i))) lw 2
```

Here, the "strategy" is to:

1. find the total number or records in the input file with (alternatively, one could use the `stats` command)

   ```
   N = system(sprintf("wc -l %s | gawk '{print $1}'", fname))
   ```
2. define a function which extracts the `i`th value from the input file

   ```
   cmd(i) = sprintf("gawk 'NR==%d{print $2;exit}' %s", i, fname)
   ```

The output is then:
[image]